# VS2010 Debugger is unable to start a program

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Recently when trying to run ASP.net Web Applications, I started receiving an error of:

`"Attaching the ProteusDebugEngine debugger to process '[9352] WebDev.WebServer40.exe' on machine 'PC' failed. Invalid pointer”`

`“OK”`

And when I click “ok” I got this message:

`“Unable to start program 'http://localhost:8888/Welcome.htm' . Element not fount”`

I am not really sure what changed on my pc. Any ideas???

Thanks

Comment: Did you try searching before posting?

Comment: have you changed anything (like a VS plugin or similar) ? see http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/624213/attaching-the-proteusdebugengine-debugger-to-process-qtagent32-exe-on-machine-failed-invalid-pointer

Answer (score 0):

Running the following in the Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010) solved this for me.

```
devenv /resetskippkgs
```